# unable to locate database on real android device?

Tags: android, sqlite

I recently developed an application which creates a database and stores data into that database. Now I have installed the application on the SD card running android 2.3.7 OS. However, I am unable to locate where this database is created on the SD card. After reading many posts , which says that the database is located in data/data//databases/ . I dont see such a folder on my sd card(when I plugged it to my computer via USB).
Please help me to determine where this file is located.

Do I have to root into the device to gain access to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is stored in `/data/data/your.package/databases/...`. That path is not on your SD card ; stuff there lives in `/sdcard`. You need root access to read `/data`.

However, you should never need to read or write it directly in normal operation. You are supposed to use the proper SQLite APIs to access it. It's much easier anyway than hacking.